# How Connect two Data Lake Store on two different subscription via Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, azure-data-lake, data-lake

So far as the question says..is it possible to mount/connect two Azure Data Lake Store that are on two different subscription locally via Hadoop? My goal is to be able to programmaticall copy files and folder from one DLS to another one.

I followed this [guide](https://medium.com/azure-data-lake/connecting-your-own-hadoop-or-spark-to-azure-data-lake-store-93d426d6a5f4) that show how it work with only one ADL and I managed to achieve that. By googleing around I did not find anthing, so I tried to modify the **core-site.xml** to make it able to read from both DLS as follow:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type</name>
        <value>ClientCredential</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url</name>
      <value>xxxx</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url</name>
      <value>xxxxx</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id</name>
      <value>yyyy</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id</name>
      <value>yyyyyyy</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.credential</name>
      <value>xxyyxh</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.credential</name>
      <value>gsgsdgsdg</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>fs.adl.impl</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.AdlFileSystem</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.adl.impl</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.Adl</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

But in this way I still can access only one DLS...an idea?

Comment: Adding this twice won't work. Is there a different credential that is associated with each of the ADLS accounts? The easiest way is to have the same credential associated with both of the accounts. Thereafter, you only need to add the configuration once.

Comment: @AmitKulkarni i shouldn't need any credential as they comes along with the token and client secrets...